# Dose any one know a good book about finding graph by equations?

Tags: graphing-functions

Can anyone help me to book about finding graph by equations?

Please help

Comment: Why not just plot it, e.g. with Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: Yes it's a good website but I want book to find some question with more explain :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the tutorials available at the [Khan Academy: Graphing Functions](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/algebra-functions/graphing_functions/v/graphing-a--basic-function) for some direction with respect to how to graph given functions. It starts with basics: like graphing lines, then parabolas, then exponential functions, etc.

For a bit of a broader view, you might want to see the menu (again, at the Khan Academy) headlined by ["Functions:"](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/algebra-functions) everything from how we define functions, to constructing functions, and graphing them. It is designed to start with more basic functions, and progress to more complicated ones.

Comment: thank you, I think if I graduate I will remember your helping :D

Comment: You're welcome! Here's the biggest tip of all: Every time you catch yourself saying "...if I graduate...", cut yourself off and say out loud: **"WHEN I graduate, since I WILL graduate, and I'll do what it takes to do so!"**